# Last column clipping issue in ListView

Tags: c#, winforms

When I reduce the client area of ListView by handling

```
WM_NCCALCSIZE
```

message, the client area adjusted correctly. But some portion of last column is clipped.That is the column header divider of last column and the text in last column is not fully visible.
This is done for placing a custom scrollbar having larger size than windows scrollbar in ListView.
If it is done with other controls like TextBox and TreeView, it behaves normally. But only the ListView clips the client area.

So is there any possible work-around or solution ?

Comment: I think your handling code and screenshot of result would be helpful here

Comment: How can I upload the screenshot here?. Please inform.

Comment: Likely a bug in ListCtrl itself. See [link]https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/749261/clistctrl-client-rect-adjustment-issue